# Passing Variables Into Custom Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, button, material-ui

I have a custom button that looks like this:

```
export default function CustomButton(isValid: any, email: any) {
    return (
        <Button
            type="submit"
            disabled={!isValid || !email}
            style={{
                background: '#6c74cc',
                borderRadius: 3,
                border: 0,
                color: 'white',
                height: 48,
                padding: '0 30px',
            }}
        >
            Remove User</Button>
    )
}
```

For now, I am just passing `isValid`and `email`as variables but these will be different for all pages where I use this button component. How can I change it so that I can **pass a list of conditions for `disabled`** as well as other parameters? and how will I call this component then?

Secondly, for now, when I use it like this in my main page, it works:

```
{CustomButton(isValid, email)}
```

but if I try calling it like this:

```
<CustomButton isValid email></CustomButton>
```

the **disability of the button doesn't work** and I can click it without fulfilling these conditions as well. How should I change it?

Comment: I think you're missing the curly braces around your props. Please have a look in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-agnesi-lh04r) to see all possible ways to pass props to a component.

Comment: The code snippet I wrote above works. I think you didn't understand my question well. Instead of ```isValid```and ```email```, I want to pass a list of conditions for the ```disabled```property because the variables passed and conditions might be different every time I call this component @AWolf

Comment: OK, I've updated the demo. If I understand it correctly you'd like to pass a prop with multiple conditions to your component and if one is falsy you'd like to disable it. You could pass an array and check it with `array.some`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a `disabled` prop and handle the condition in the parent:

```
const disabled = !isValid || !email;
// example with other conditions:
// const disabled = !isValid || !email ||!username || !password;
//...
<CustomButton disabled={disabled} />
```

then the component can simply be:

```
type ButtonProps = { disabled: boolean };
export default function CustomButton({ disabled }: ButtonProps) { // you also forgot the destructure your props which is why it wasnt working
    return (
        <Button
            type="submit"
            disabled={disabled}
            style={{
                background: '#6c74cc',
                borderRadius: 3,
                border: 0,
                color: 'white',
                height: 48,
                padding: '0 30px',
            }}
        >
            Remove User</Button>
    )
}
```

Comment: In Typescript, ```({disabled})```doesn't work. It says ```Binding element 'disabled' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)```. When I add ```disabled:any```, any gives the same error and the quick fix is to remove destructuring.

Comment: React expects a props object for functional components. So `function(props) { const disabled = props.disabled; }` can be written as `function({disabled: Boolean}) { ... }`. For more details to descructuring have a look at the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring).

Comment: The following [React Typescript cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#function-components) is a great resource to learn more about React with Typescript - I'm also still learning TS with React.

Comment: Thanks! How exactly could I write these conditions in the component? If I try ```<CustomButton disabled={{isValid: false, email: false}} />```I get an error on ```disabled```that ```Type '{ isValid: boolean; email: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)```and if I remove the inner brackets, I still get syntax errors.

Comment: So the way I set it up, you're not passing `email` or `isValid` into the component. you do all the calculation in the parent and all the component cares about is whether or not `disabled` is true/false. for example: `<CustomButtom disabled={!isValid || !email} />`. or you can also save it as a variable. updated my answer to reflect

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, you want to put the responsibility (when is valid) inside `<Button />`, which is an incorrect approach.

Each component should be agnostic to each other. Meaning, each component shouldn't care from where it gets the props. So if you want to pass a list of conditions, do it outside of the `<Button />` and then pass the conditions as a prop. In case there's a pattern, you can simply create a different `<ConditionalButton ...listOfProps />` that prints the `<Button />` accordingly.

Regarding your second question. `isValid` and `email` are true, so `!isValid (false) || !email (false) => false`. Therefore, `disabled` is false.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. Could you give an example on how I could make and pass the listOfProps exactly?

Comment: @JohnNeuland listOfProps was just an example. What I meant in a pattern was if you use the button in different places and determine it's valid based on multiple factors, then you can wrap it inside another component (search Higher Order Component). But I feel like I don't answer you question. Can you be more speicifc with your question?

Comment: The code snippet I wrote above works but instead of ```isValid```and ```email```, I want to pass a list of conditions for the disabled property because the variables passed and conditions might be different every time I call this component. For example, on one page I want ```disabled = {!isValid || !email}```but on another page I want it to be ```{!isValid || !password}```. So I want to pass these variables when I call the button component.

Comment: @JohnNeuland why would not just passing a boolean that is being determined in the parent component?